# Get post-meta value of all custom-posts - lowest to highest year-count?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, loop, taxonomy

probably tough to describe:

I have a `custom-post-type` called `wr_event` and a custom-field for it called `event_date`.

I have a lot of posts and each of those posts has set an `event_date`. Pretty straight forward.

All I'd like to do now is list all the years in which `events` have been posted.
So I'd like to have this …

```
2012 | 2011 | 2010 | 2009 | 2008
```

How do I do that? I thought of looping through all posts and listing the years, but somehow I can't figure out how to do so.

```
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      global $post;
      $this_year = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_date', true );
      $this_year = date('Y', $this_year);
      echo $this_year;
  endwhile;
```

What's the best and simplest solution to do so?

**UPDATE**

```
    rsort( $years ); // sorts the years array into reverse order
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        echo '<a href="#'.$year.'" name="y'.$year.'" class="inactive">'.$year.'</a> <span class="sep">|</span> ';
    }
```

Comment: How are your dates stored? What is the format?

Comment: If they are timestamp-based then you can use a numeric ordering within the query instead of retroactively ordering (faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do the job:

```
global $post;
$years = array();
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $this_year = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_date', true );
    if ( $this_year = date( 'Y', $this_year ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $this_year, $years ) ) {
            $years[] = $this_year;
        }
    }
endwhile;
rsort( $years ); // sorts the years array into reverse order
echo implode( ' | ', $years );
```

to reduce queries, you can save everything into a [transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API):

```
global $post;
$transient = 'all-post-years';
$timeout   = 14400; // 4 hours

if ( false === $out = get_transient( $transient ) ) {

    $years = array();
    $loop  = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $this_year = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_date', true );
        if ( $this_year = date( 'Y', $this_year ) ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $this_year, $years ) ) {
                $years[] = $this_year;
            }
        }
    endwhile;

    rsort( $years ); // sorts the years array into reverse order

    foreach ( $years as $year ) {
        $out .= '<a href="#' . $year . '" name="y' . $year . '" class="inactive">' . $year . '</a> <span class="sep">|</span> ';
    }

    if ( $out ) {
        set_transient( $transient, $out, $timeout );
    }

}

echo $out;
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. My `$args` array looks like this … `$args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'wr_event', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, // show all posts 
      'meta_key' => 'event_date',   
     );` Is that a problem performansewise? I'm looping through all posts a second time on this page?

Comment: i've updated the answer to show how you can cache the results using the transients API, so the query is not run on every pageload.

Comment: Thank you, however that doesn't work for me. `echo $out` is always empty. Moreover I updated my question with the `foreach loop` I do on `$years`. I do not want to `implode` the array. Any last ideas why the code you posted doesn't work for me? I tried it exaclty like you suggested but `echo $out` doesn't show anything.

Comment: i've updated my answer based on your foreach loop. hard to say why it isn't working - try putting in `print_r($years)` to check if the array has something in it. you'll also need to delete the transient as it lasts for 4hrs. set it to 10 seconds while you're debugging.